# "Importing" changes from a branch to a rebased branch with git

Tags: git, branch, rebase

I've been working on a project *foo* that is a fork of another project *bar*, doing branch and so on. I'd like now to offer my changes to the original project too.

Firstly I have set up things for the future rebase:

```
git remote add bar git://bar/bar.git
git fetch bar
git checkout -b bar-master bar/master
```

Now, for a given branch foo-branch made for the project *foo*, I have ran:

```
git checkout foo-branch
git checkout -b bar-branch
git checkout bar-branch
git rebase bar-master
```

I can see from:

```
git log --format=one
```

that the rebase went OK.

Now I'm going to do changes/commits in either foo-branch or bar-branch.

My question is: how can I "import" the commits from one branch (eg foo-branch) onto the branch for the other project (in the given example, bar-branch)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `rebase` you could simply merge the data, this will be `fast-forward merge` so it wouldn't introduce any merge commits.

Or.. if you want single commit, you could use `cherry-pick` git command
Or.. if you want many commits being imported at once you could use `rebase` with `--onto` switch.

Comment: Late reply, but yeah, this is it. Since a not so old version of git, you can even cherry-pick simply using a branch name.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that feature - thanks (: Please also note that cherry-picking commit will change its SHA (Mr. Obvious note)

Answer (score 0):

So since you've rebased your fork with the upstream (original) repo, your all set for a fast-forward merge - and thats a great start.

To push to different repos, you simply specify the given repo in your push command. To push to `foo` you would run...

```
git push foo <branch-name>
```

To bush to the `bar` repo, run...

```
git push bar <branch-name>
```

To pull from foo or bar, its the same set of commands, but with pull instead of push.

Its useful to understand that because git is already treating foo and bar as separate remotes, you dont need to make a special branch for each repo. Git already does this for you behind the scenes. Run the following set of commands with the same `<branch>` to see what I mean

```
git log foo/<branch>
git log bar/<branch>
```

When you run a `git pull` command, thats a shortcut for `git fetch <remote>` and `git merge <branch>`. When you run a fetch command, git creates/updates all that branches repositories on your local repository - all naming convention of `<remote-name>/<branch-name`. These aren't branches you can directly checkout, but you can run logs against them, merge from and and rebase from them.